# Automatically fill up the Google Map search bar (Address Picker)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to present my users with a text box wherein they can type in their address. As they type their address, there's a new window will open (Google map) and automatically fill up the search box in Google map. I want to provide the users with suggestions/predictions of what address they are trying to type. I'm also concerned about the relevance of this address (e.g. that the address is not an address halfway across the world).

How to automatically fill the search box in Google map from the inputted address text box from another website?

E.g In my website, there's a text box and I input an address in that text box and when I click enter in that text box there's a new window appear and display the Google Map with search bar (in that search bar, the address is already there)

Is this possible in javascript and jquery? Please help me. I'm newbie in those PL. Thank you

Here's the code:

```
  (function($, window, document, undefined){

var defaults = {
bounds: true,
country: null,
map: false,
details: false,
detailsAttribute: "name",
autoselect: true,
location: false,

mapOptions: {
  zoom: 14,
  scrollwheel: false,
  mapTypeId: "roadmap"
},

markerOptions: {
  draggable: false
},

maxZoom: 16,
types: ['geocode'],
blur: false
 };


var componentTypes = ("street_address route intersection political " +
"country administrative_area_level_1 administrative_area_level_2 " +
"administrative_area_level_3 colloquial_area locality sublocality " +
"neighborhood premise subpremise postal_code natural_feature airport " +
"park point_of_interest post_box street_number floor room " +
"lat lng viewport location " +
"formatted_address location_type bounds").split(" ");

 var placesDetails = ("id url website vicinity reference name rating " +
"international_phone_number icon formatted_phone_number").split(" ");

// The actual plugin constructor.
function GeoComplete(input, options) {

this.options = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options);

this.input = input;
this.$input = $(input);

this._defaults = defaults;
this._name = 'geocomplete';

this.init();
}

 // Initialize all parts of the plugin.
 $.extend(GeoComplete.prototype, {
 init: function(){
  this.initMap();
  this.initMarker();
  this.initGeocoder();
  this.initDetails();
  this.initLocation();
},

// Initialize the map but only if the option `map` was set.
// This will create a `map` within the given container
// using the provided `mapOptions` or link to the existing map instance.
initMap: function(){
  if (!this.options.map){ return; }

  if (typeof this.options.map.setCenter == "function"){
    this.map = this.options.map;
    return;
  }

  this.map = new google.maps.Map(
    $(this.options.map)[0],
    this.options.mapOptions
  );

  // add click event listener on the map
  google.maps.event.addListener(
    this.map,
    'click',
    $.proxy(this.mapClicked, this)
  );

  google.maps.event.addListener(
    this.map,
    'zoom_changed',
    $.proxy(this.mapZoomed, this)
  );
  },

// Add a marker with the provided `markerOptions` but only
// if the option was set. Additionally it listens for the `dragend` event
// to notify the plugin about changes.
initMarker: function(){
  if (!this.map){ return; }
  var options = $.extend(this.options.markerOptions, { map: this.map });

  if (options.disabled){ return; }

  this.marker = new google.maps.Marker(options);

  google.maps.event.addListener(
    this.marker,
    'dragend',
    $.proxy(this.markerDragged, this)
  );
 },

  // Associate the input with the autocompleter and create a geocoder
 // to fall back when the autocompleter does not return a value.
 initGeocoder: function(){

  var options = {
    types: this.options.types,
    bounds: this.options.bounds === true ? null : this.options.bounds,
    componentRestrictions: this.options.componentRestrictions
  };

  if (this.options.country){
    options.componentRestrictions = {country: this.options.country};
  }

  this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    this.input, options
  );

  this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  // Bind autocomplete to map bounds but only if there is a map
  // and `options.bindToMap` is set to true.
  if (this.map && this.options.bounds === true){
    this.autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);
  }

  // Watch `place_changed` events on the autocomplete input field.
  google.maps.event.addListener(
    this.autocomplete,
    'place_changed',
    $.proxy(this.placeChanged, this)
  );

  // Prevent parent form from being submitted if user hit enter.
  this.$input.keypress(function(event){
    if (event.keyCode === 13){ return false; }
  });

  // Listen for "geocode" events and trigger find action.
  this.$input.bind("geocode", $.proxy(function(){
    this.find();
  }, this));

  // Trigger find action when input element is blured out.
  // (Usefull for typing partial location and tabing to the next field
  // or clicking somewhere else.)
  if (this.options.blur === true){
    this.$input.blur($.proxy(function(){
      this.find();
    }, this));
   }
  },

// Prepare a given DOM structure to be populated when we got some data.
// This will cycle through the list of component types and map the
// corresponding elements.
initDetails: function(){
  if (!this.options.details){ return; }

  var $details = $(this.options.details),
    attribute = this.options.detailsAttribute,
    details = {};

  function setDetail(value){
    details[value] = $details.find("[" +  attribute + "=" + value + "]");
  }

  $.each(componentTypes, function(index, key){
    setDetail(key);
    setDetail(key + "_short");
  });

  $.each(placesDetails, function(index, key){
    setDetail(key);
  });

  this.$details = $details;
  this.details = details;
},

// Set the initial location of the plugin if the `location` options was set.
// This method will care about converting the value into the right format.
initLocation: function() {

  var location = this.options.location, latLng;

  if (!location) { return; }

  if (typeof location == 'string') {
    this.find(location);
    return;
  }

  if (location instanceof Array) {
    latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location[0], location[1]);
  }

  if (location instanceof google.maps.LatLng){
    latLng = location;
  }

  if (latLng){
    if (this.map){ this.map.setCenter(latLng); }
    if (this.marker){ this.marker.setPosition(latLng); }
  }
},

// Look up a given address. If no `address` was specified it uses
// the current value of the input.
find: function(address){
  this.geocode({
    address: address || this.$input.val()
  });
},

// Requests details about a given location.
// Additionally it will bias the requests to the provided bounds.
geocode: function(request){
  if (this.options.bounds && !request.bounds){
    if (this.options.bounds === true){
      request.bounds = this.map && this.map.getBounds();
    } else {
      request.bounds = this.options.bounds;
    }
  }

  if (this.options.country){
    request.region = this.options.country;
  }

  this.geocoder.geocode(request, $.proxy(this.handleGeocode, this));
},

// Get the selected result. If no result is selected on the list, then get
// the first result from the list.
selectFirstResult: function() {
  //$(".pac-container").hide();

  var selected = '';
  // Check if any result is selected.
  if ($(".pac-item-selected")['0']) {
    selected = '-selected';
  }

  // Get the first suggestion's text.
  var $span1 = $(".pac-container .pac-item" + selected + ":first span:nth-child(2)").text();
  var $span2 = $(".pac-container .pac-item" + selected + ":first span:nth-child(3)").text();

  // Get the inputted address from LAP
  var 

  // Adds the additional information, if available.
  var firstResult = $span1;
  if ($span2) {
    firstResult += " - " + $span2;
  }

  this.$input.val(firstResult);

  return firstResult;
},

// Handles the geocode response. If more than one results was found
// it triggers the "geocode:multiple" events. If there was an error
// the "geocode:error" event is fired.
handleGeocode: function(results, status){
  if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    var result = results[0];
    this.$input.val(result.formatted_address);
    this.update(result);

    if (results.length > 1){
      this.trigger("geocode:multiple", results);
    }

  } else {
    this.trigger("geocode:error", status);
  }
},

// Triggers a given `event` with optional `arguments` on the input.
trigger: function(event, argument){
  this.$input.trigger(event, [argument]);
},

// Set the map to a new center by passing a `geometry`.
// If the geometry has a viewport, the map zooms out to fit the bounds.
// Additionally it updates the marker position.
center: function(geometry){

  if (geometry.viewport){
    this.map.fitBounds(geometry.viewport);
    if (this.map.getZoom() > this.options.maxZoom){
      this.map.setZoom(this.options.maxZoom);
    }
  } else {
    this.map.setZoom(this.options.maxZoom);
    this.map.setCenter(geometry.location);
  }

  if (this.marker){
    this.marker.setPosition(geometry.location);
    this.marker.setAnimation(this.options.markerOptions.animation);
  }
},

// Update the elements based on a single places or geoocoding response
// and trigger the "geocode:result" event on the input.
update: function(result){

  if (this.map){
    this.center(result.geometry);
  }

  if (this.$details){
    this.fillDetails(result);
  }

  this.trigger("geocode:result", result);
},

// Populate the provided elements with new `result` data.
// This will lookup all elements that has an attribute with the given
// component type.
fillDetails: function(result){

  var data = {},
    geometry = result.geometry,
    viewport = geometry.viewport,
    bounds = geometry.bounds;

  // Create a simplified version of the address components.
  $.each(result.address_components, function(index, object){
    var name = object.types[0];
    data[name] = object.long_name;
    data[name + "_short"] = object.short_name;
  });

  // Add properties of the places details.
  $.each(placesDetails, function(index, key){
    data[key] = result[key];
  });

  // Add infos about the address and geometry.
  $.extend(data, {
    formatted_address: result.formatted_address,
    location_type: geometry.location_type || "PLACES",
    viewport: viewport,
    bounds: bounds,
    location: geometry.location,
    lat: geometry.location.lat(),
    lng: geometry.location.lng()
  });

  // Set the values for all details.
  $.each(this.details, $.proxy(function(key, $detail){
    var value = data[key];
    this.setDetail($detail, value);
  }, this));

  this.data = data;
},

// Assign a given `value` to a single `$element`.
// If the element is an input, the value is set, otherwise it updates
// the text content.
setDetail: function($element, value){

  if (value === undefined){
    value = "";
  } else if (typeof value.toUrlValue == "function"){
    value = value.toUrlValue();
  }

  if ($element.is(":input")){
    $element.val(value);
  } else {
    $element.text(value);
  }
},

// Fire the "geocode:dragged" event and pass the new position.
markerDragged: function(event){
  this.trigger("geocode:dragged", event.latLng);
},

mapClicked: function(event) {
    this.trigger("geocode:click", event.latLng);
},

mapZoomed: function(event) {
  this.trigger("geocode:zoom", this.map.getZoom());
},

// Restore the old position of the marker to the last now location.
resetMarker: function(){
  this.marker.setPosition(this.data.location);
  this.setDetail(this.details.lat, this.data.location.lat());
  this.setDetail(this.details.lng, this.data.location.lng());
},

 // Update the plugin after the user has selected an autocomplete entry.
 // If the place has no geometry it passes it to the geocoder.
 placeChanged: function(){
  var place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();

  if (!place || !place.geometry){
    if (this.options.autoselect) {
      // Automatically selects the highlighted item or the first item from the
      // suggestions list.
      var autoSelection = this.selectFirstResult();
      this.find(autoSelection);
    }
  } else {
    // Use the input text if it already gives geometry.
    this.update(place);
  }
}
 });

 // A plugin wrapper around the constructor.
// Pass `options` with all settings that are different from the default.
// The attribute is used to prevent multiple instantiations of the plugin.
 $.fn.geocomplete = function(options) {

var attribute = 'plugin_geocomplete';

// If you call `.geocomplete()` with a string as the first parameter
// it returns the corresponding property or calls the method with the
// following arguments.
if (typeof options == "string"){

  var instance = $(this).data(attribute) || $(this).geocomplete().data(attribute),
    prop = instance[options];

  if (typeof prop == "function"){
    prop.apply(instance, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    return $(this);
  } else {
    if (arguments.length == 2){
      prop = arguments[1];
    }
    return prop;
  }
  } else {
  return this.each(function() {
    // Prevent against multiple instantiations.
    var instance = $.data(this, attribute);
    if (!instance) {
      instance = new GeoComplete( this, options );
      $.data(this, attribute, instance);
    }
  });
    }
   };

  })( jQuery, window, document );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFIK, the search bar which is used in Google maps search api is a simple textbox (`input type="text"`) and its `id` is `pac-input`

```
$('#pac-input').val($('your address element').val()); //copy the value
$('#pac-input').focus(); //focus might trigger automatically
```

### [**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/xHT3k/1/)

Comment: How can I auto fill up the search box in Google Map? From the address text box in my website?

Comment: You need to use JS/jQuery `$('#pac-input').val($('your address element')); //copy the value`

Comment: Can you give me the right code for that, please? Sorry, I'm new in those PLs

Comment: what do you mean "your address element"?

Comment: @user3709362 I'm not sure what makes it too hard to bring it up.. `"your address element"` refers to textbox where user enters the address.. I have added fiddle in my answer, have a look into it.

Comment: Hi, when I create a new files and copy your scripts, and run the html file, the map is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Read document for `geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();`

and try this:

```
var input_address = $('your address element').val();
geocoder.geocode({address: input_address}, reverseGeocodeResult);

function reverseGeocodeResult(results, status) {
        currentReverseGeocodeResponse = results;
        if (status == 'OK') {
        if (results.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById('cong_viec_dia_chi').innerHTML = 'None';
        } else {
        document.getElementById('cong_viec_dia_chi').innerHTML = results[0].formatted_address;
        }
        } else {
        document.getElementById('cong_viec_dia_chi').innerHTML = 'can't get address';
        }
    }
```

Update: demo here

http://jsfiddle.net/HoangHieu/x8dSP/3626/

http://jsfiddle.net/HoangHieu/x8dSP/3631/

Comment: Is that code, is copy the inputted address in textbox from my website into google maps?

Comment: Handle even input completed or event key press. 

<input type="text" onKeyUp="getaddress()" id="input_address" />

function getaddress(){
  // Copy my solution in here 
}

Comment: where's the link? Where do I put in my existing js? Please see the code that I displayed

Comment: @HoangHieu There is no need for geocoding here as per user's question.

Comment: I codding solution, please waiting menute

Comment: @HoangHieu Too complicate.  Here user already has it with google maps `How to automatically fill the search box in Google map`

Comment: My solution is get value of search box and find it with GOOGLE MAP, google map will be return result with search box value. 
it's standing requirements, fill to search box of google and search it with google of user

**E.g In my website, there's a text box and I input an address in that text box and when I click enter in that text box there's a new window appear and display the Google Map with search bar (in that search bar, the address is already there)**